# WebStorm freezes for a long time on Ionic2 project with hot reload

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, ionic-framework, ionic2, webstorm

I created a simple Ionic2/3 project and just setup WebStorm, with all default settings.

When running the project with `ionic serve`, hot reload works as expected.

However, there is a strange and very annoying behaviour:

- When I stay (I keep the mouse cursor into) in the IDE, I can write some text then `cmd+S`many times, it rebuilds the project very fastly (200ms) and does not freeze the IDE at all.
- But when I click outside of the IDE: it starts a build too (which is normal I guess because WebStorm save edited files at this time), and when I go back to the IDE, whenever it is, I have a very long (> 3s) freeze time while I'm completely blocked (I can't even type something).

Notes:

- It seems to happen more on html files than on js files.
- I'm using MacOS Sierra on a MBP 2013
- I was using PyCharm (from IntelliJ too), with the exact same problem. No problem with SublimeText3. It seems to be IntelliJ related.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure to exclude `www` folder from indexing (`Mark directory as/Excluded` action in folder right-click menu) to avoid re-indexing project each time the generated files are flashed to disk (which usually happens when you move focus out from the IDE and back). If this doesn't help, try disabling  '*Synchronize files on frame activation*' (`Preferences | Appearance & Behavior| System settings`)

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for too. Thanks lena!

Comment: Worked for me as well :)

Comment: I guess you may need to exclude `platforms` folder as well as some js build artefacts are being placed there also.